# enable sticky post option for custom post types wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress latest version 3.3.2
I have madecustom post types and now I want sticky post option in custom posts. I am able to do this by editing the core wordpress file metaboxes.php, but I want to do the same without touching any core files of wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

For your needs I would recommend the "More fields" plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/

You can choose the type of the custom field and attach to one or more custom post types. To create sticky posts, maybe you should use a checkbox for the custom field and query the latest N checked custom posts/sticky posts :)

I hope it does make sense for you.

Good luck! :)

Comment: I am able to make checkbox as a custom field without plugin. I was wondering if I could use a function to enable the sticky posts options that is the inbuilt wordpress functionality.

Comment: You need to write yourself this "premium" feature.